# Any argument in Expecting function in easymock scalatest

Tags: scala, easymock, scalatest

I have just started to use scalatest for java code and in that we are using easymock to create mocks .

I have a situation where I want to do something like this.

```
expecting{
       objA.function(x$1, x$2).andReturn(objectB)
      }
```

For the place holder **x$1,x$2** I want to call the function passing similar to something like `anyObject()` in java .

Kindly suggest something that could replace the placeholder.

Comment: I am struggling with the same. Tried `val l = mock[List[String]];
      expecting { l.map(isA(classOf[String => Int])).andReturn(List(1,2,3)) } ...`, but it fails with _"2 matchers expected, 1 recorded.
This exception usually occurs when matchers are mixed with raw values when recording a method"_

Answer (score 0):

Using methods available on Mockito (not sure if you're using it):

e.g.

```
def any[T : ClassTag]: T = org.mockito.Matchers.any(implicitly[ClassTag[T]].runtimeClass).asInstanceOf[T]
```

and you can use it as

```
val a = mock[Foo]
doReturn(fooResult).when(a).fooMethod(any[FooInput])
```

Comment: The question is about EasyMock, not Mockito.